# Transport Error :: Jgit :: git-upload-pack not permitted

Tags: java, git, eclipse, gitlab, jgit

Getting the following error while performing the git operations with jgit library api's from java applications. This application is running on tomcat inside docker container.

Exception stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://gitlab.com/xxxxx/testproject.git: git-upload-pack not permitted on 'https://gitlab.com/xxxxx/testproject.git/'
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.call(LsRemoteCommand.java:128)
    at com.test.vcs.JGitUploadPackTest.testRepoUpdate(JGitUploadPackTest.java:35)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://gitlab.com/xxxxx/testproject.git: git-upload-pack not permitted on 'https://gitlab.com/xxxxx/testproject.git/'
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:167)
    ... 135 common frames omitted
```

Note: JGIT dependency version: 5.7.0.202003110725-r

Steps to reproduce the issue:

```java
public void getRefBranches() throws IOException, GitAPIException {
        FileRepositoryBuilder builder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
        Repository repository = builder.readEnvironment().findGitDir(new File("${projectLocation}")).build();
        Git git = new Git(repository);
        CredentialsProvider credentialProvider = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("userName", "password");

        LsRemoteCommand listRemoteReferences = git.lsRemote();
        listRemoteReferences.setCredentialsProvider(credentialProvider);
        listRemoteReferences.setRemote("https://gitlab.com/xxxxx/testproject.git/");
        listRemoteReferences.setHeads(true);
        listRemoteReferences.setTags(false);
        Collection<Ref> remoteBranches = listRemoteReferences.call();
    }
```

Comment: This is not a question, but an answer to the question of what can go wrong using outdated software. You are more than three years and 28(!) releases behind.

Comment: Hey @howlger I have tried with the latest version of the jgit (5.7.0.202003110725-r).
With that version also I'm getting the same error.

Comment: How did you pass the Gitlab access token? https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1091325/ By the way, the latest JGit version is 5.8 which has been released two days ago.

Comment: Im passing the userName and password as CredentialsProvider credentialProvider = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("userName", "password");

Comment: @howlger I don't think this is something, which is fixed in jgit 5.8 version. And FYI in maven repository latest version is 5.7

Comment: JGit is actively developed and used by so many that it is very unlikely that this is a bug of JGit, but rather something on your side: missing permission, problem accessing the remote repository or caused by your code. Therefore show a [minimal example to reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Did it work once before? Does it work without/outside of Docker? Can you fetch from on the command line in Docker?

Comment: @howlger added the sample code to replicate the issue. It do work from command line in docker. One strange thing observed is some times it works and sometimes it didn't work. Checked the same request using curl command with same url and headers, sometimes it is giving 200 and sometimes 403. So Is there anythings to check from the system end. If so what are the things to be checked.

Comment: I have no glue why it does not work in Docker on the command line sometimes (I'm not a Docker expert). Newer version of JGit works either with JSch or Apache MINA as SSH client. Does your Maven dependencies include a `jsch` or `sshd-core` JAR? If not, try to use [`org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.apache`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.apache) or if this does not work to the old [`org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.jsch`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.jsch) instead of `org.eclipse.jgit`.

Comment: Finally found the issue, error is due to the default HttpConnection.  
Updated the code to use apache HttpClientConnectionFactory.

`HttpTransport.setConnectionFactory(new HttpClientConnectionFactory());`

Thanks @howlger, for your inputs

Answer (score 1):

The exception message points to that fact that the credentials that you have used do not have the right permissions to "push" to the gitlab repo.
Please check the credentials you have used.

Comment: Yes Credentials I have used have all the permissions required. One surprising thing is it working properly some time and some times it is not working and throwing the above exception.